# Android tv notification Access

Tags: android, permissions, notifications, system, television

Me & another member of the Android TV dev community on Google+ were working on a project and it requires access to the notification access. ex:the permission pushbullet asks for so it can mirror your phone notifications. And when trying to execute it it pushes me back to the open app screen and does nothing. Anyone's help would be great! Thanks!
Here's the project if it helps--https://github.com/Fleker/AndroidTVNotification

Anthony

Answer (score -1):

Following exception appeared when I execute your app,

> 09-08 22:24:15.380: E/AndroidRuntime(24570): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS }

Inside MainActivity.java, how do you want to handle the intent?

```
    public void buttonClicked(View v){

        ...

        case R.id.btnSettings:
            i =new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
            startActivity(i);

    }
}
```